# Multithreaded correctness: Using synchronized block

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

I am using the CMU Sphinx Speech Recognizer library ([Link to source](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/)) that makes some use of `synchronized` blocks.

One example block from the RecognizerTask:

```
Event mailbox;

[...]

public void start() {
    synchronized (this.mailbox) {
        this.mailbox.notifyAll();
        this.mailbox = Event.START;
    }
}
```

The code works without any problems, however BugFinder gives this warning:

> Bug: Synchronization on RecognizerTask.mailbox in futile attempt to
>   guard it
>
> This method synchronizes on a field in what appears to be an
>   attempt to guard against simultaneous updates to that field. But
>   guarding a field gets a lock on the referenced object, not on the
>   field. This may not provide the mutual exclusion you need, and other
>   threads might be obtaining locks on the referenced objects (for other
>   purposes). An example of this pattern would be:
>
> ```
> private Long myNtfSeqNbrCounter = new Long(0);
> private Long getNotificationSequenceNumber() {
>      Long result = null;
>      synchronized(myNtfSeqNbrCounter) {
>          result = new Long(myNtfSeqNbrCounter.longValue() + 1);
>          myNtfSeqNbrCounter = new Long(result.longValue());
>      }
>      return result;
>  }
> ```

To be honest, I don't quite understand the bug description and what is supposed to be wrong in this case.
Is a global variable not a field? And if not, how can I improve the code?

**/edit:** This is the only part where `Event.wait()` is called:

```
Event todo = Event.NONE;
        synchronized (this.mailbox) {
            todo = this.mailbox;
            /* If we're idle then wait for something to happen. */
            if (state == State.IDLE && todo == Event.NONE) {
                try {
                    //Log.d(getClass().getName(), "waiting");
                    this.mailbox.wait();
                    todo = this.mailbox;
                    //Log.d(getClass().getName(), "got" + todo);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    /* Quit main loop. */
                    //Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Interrupted waiting for mailbox, shutting down");
                    todo = Event.SHUTDOWN;
                }
            }
            /* Reset the mailbox before releasing, to avoid race condition. */
            this.mailbox = Event.NONE;
        }
```

This code is actually using a `synchronized` statement as well. Does it make sense at all to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it applies in your case. You have a call to `notifyAll()` which means that somewhere in the code of the other threads there is a matching `wait()` call:

```
synchronized (this.mailbox) {
    this.mailbox.wait();        
}
```

meaning that the other thread will relinquish the lock while waiting to be notified.

Your code inspector is probably confused by the line:

```
this.mailbox = Event.START;
```

meaning that you might be concurrently modifying this object, such that if another thread attempts to get the lock on `this.mailbox`, it will see a different object. However, I do think that since:

1. `this.mailbox` is globally visible
2. assigns of references are atomic
3. the lock generates a fence

all threads should have an updated view of the synchronization object at all times.

Comment: You are correct. The warning is correct that the synchronization doesn't do what most people would think it does. But in this case, it doesn't matter. The thread is only holding the 'wrong' lock in a place where it doesn't matter -- the 'improperly' locked code requires no lock as it atomically assigns a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Please see my updated question - would you recommend removing the `synchronized` completely?

Comment: Actually you can't because calls to wait or notify/notifyAll on an object must be inside a synchronized block on the same object.

Answer (score 4):

the synchronized block "captures" the lock for the given object, in your case for the object denoted by `mailbox`. Once you change the variable `mailbox` to point to a different object, other threads can "capture" the lock for this object without a problem, since it is not taken.

Note that the lock is for objects, and not for references!

now, concider the following [pseudo code]:

```
synchronised (myObject) { 
  myObject = new Object();
  i += 5; //assume i is an instance variable
}
```

practically there is no lock here! every thread is creating a new object in the lock block, and the modification of i is not synchronized!

Comment: that is why we need to create a final object and use it for locking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Please see my updated question - would you recommend removing the `synchronized` completely?